# Checking if a bit is set in SQL

Tags: sql, bit-manipulation

I've inherited the following code, and want to confirm what specifically it's doing:

```
select 
      * 
from 
      test_table
where
      value & (8 << (8-1)) = 0
```

It appears to me as if this is checking if a specific bit in `value` is set or not, but I'm not entirely sure which. Can anyone shed some light on the logic here?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: 0x400, so it's checking bit 10 (11th bit)

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? DB2? Firebird?

Comment: I'm using Netezza